# Change the dropdown option text with no value on page load

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to override the text of one of the Dropdown option using jQuery but it's not working.

I want to display the option text **All Categories** instead of **Categories**

**HTML Snippet**

```
<select name="filter-cat">
<option value="">Categories</option>
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
</select>
```

**Js Code:**

```
jQuery ('[name=filter-cat] option').filter(function() { 
return ($(this).text() == 'Categories'); //To select Blue
}).prop('text', "All Categories");
```

Please, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Text can be changed with below function as

[CODEPEN LINK](https://codepen.io/soniajain/pen/zmRdXg)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('select option:contains("Categories")').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);

   $this.text($this.text().replace("Categories","All Categories"));    
});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('select[name=filter-cat]').find('option[value=""]').text('All Categories');
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1a3kftb6/)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a way you could do it:

First find the select-element by filtering on name, then look at the option element that contains the text *Categories*, and lastly change the text to *All Categories*

```js
$(function() {
  $('select[name=filter-cat] option:contains("Categories")').text('All Categories');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="filter-cat">
  <option value="">Categories</option>
  <option value="abc">ABC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[name=filter-cat] option').filter(function(el) {
     return $(el).text() === 'Categories';
}).text('All Categories');
```